# can't click on div element through text

Tags: python, html, selenium, innertext

I am trying to automate some downloads for my employer. I am using selenium with python and chromedriver.

I'm stuck at clicking this div element which is a part of a javascript drop down.

```
<div class="item " idx="2" style="" title="">N53AC : BABY MILK UP TO 6 MONTHS</div>
```

I've been able to click this button using vbscript by looking for the innerText attribute in internet explorer.

I've already tried this

```
elemf = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("div")

for element in elemf:
    #print(element.get_attribute("innerhtml"))
    if element.get_attribute("innerhtml")=="N53AC : BABY MILK UP TO 6 MONTHS" or element.get_attribute("innertext")=="N53AC : BABY MILK UP TO 6 MONTHS" or element.text=="N53AC : BABY MILK UP TO 6 MONTHS":
        element.click()
```

Any leads? I am a complete newbie in html.

Comment: Can you post a link to the webpage? I would suggest copying the xpath for the button and use `driver.find_element_by_xpath()`

Comment: Can you share exception log? BTW you should use `innerHTML` instead of `innerhtml` and `innerText` instead of `innertext`. Also try `XPath` `//div[.="N53AC : BABY MILK UP TO 6 MONTHS"]`

Comment: Try with `if 'N53AC' in element.text: ...`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

The main issue in your code is you are trying to `find_elements_by_tag_name("div");` which will be numerous on the current `HTML DOM`. Instead you need to narrow down your search to something like:

```
elemf = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='item ']");
```

Now we can get into a loop and call `click()` method as follows:

```
for element in elemf:
    my_attribute = element.get_attribute("innerHTML")
    if my_attribute == "N53AC : BABY MILK UP TO 6 MONTHS"
        element.click()
        break
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.